# How do you get the sql server username of the currently executing command in a CLR Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I know that SqlContext.WindowsIdentity returns the current user that is executing the command (in a CLR trigger), however, this only works for windows authenticated users. How do I get the username if it's a sql server user instead? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `SUSER_NAME()` function in SQL server. This will return the current user.

Answer (score 5):

Try using SYSTEM_USER.

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use context of the current connection and get all you need from the connection object.

Like this (in C#):

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
```